# No Method declared with Objective-C Selector for Notification UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, xcode7, swift2

After the recent update of Xcode, this code that used to work no longer works. Most of the Selector(":") has an auto correction with the exception for this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}
```

which flags an error:

> No method declared with Objective C selector 'keyboardWillSHow:'

This image show different attempts which have all failed.

[image]

What is the new syntax for this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assign the `Selector` as below:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
```

And the method to update what you want:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

     //Update UI or Do Something

}
```

Same way you can do for `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 example:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClass.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil);
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClass.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil);

// MARK: - Actions

@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillShow called")
}

@objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillHide called")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The swift syntax changed. Try this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #Selector(ClassThatHasTheSelector.keyboardWillShow), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
```

Comment: It still flags an error: Type: 'SignInViewController' has no member 'KeyboardWillShow'. Unless you haven't updated you Xcode, this code will work.

Comment: It can't find that method. Make sure keyboardWillShow is available in that class and the names match (I noticed the error message capitalized Keyboard). It's unorthodox to start a method name with a capital letter.

Comment: keyBoardWillShow wasn't capitalised: sorry for the typo. Still flags with the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Try self.keyboardWillShow instead of the class name.

Comment: I already tried that. Didn't work. I think this is new problem with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issues and also find out that the class you refer on must also be subclassed from **NSObject** (which is not necc. the case in Swift) Otherwise you get the message

```
error: argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'yourMethod(notification:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 syntax (just like Sohil's above):

```
    func someMethod(sender: Any?) {
      ...
    }

    func someBlockCallingWithSelector() {
      someObject.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someMethod), for: .valueChanged) 
    }
```