# How to use Objective C selectors as arguments when subscribing to NSNotifications?

Tags: objective-c, swift, selector

I have the following subscription in swift. I need to know when the keyboard will show to move the view up. It compiles and works as expected but I don't know how to get rid of this warning. "No method declared with Objective-C selector'keyboardWillShow'"

```
// Subscribing class to recieve the notification
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
// Shifting view's frame up
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}
// Getting keyboard height
func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Please, check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366116/no-method-declared-with-objective-c-selector-for-notification-uikeyboardwillshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#selector`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pointing up that this question was already answered :) I didn't find it on google or as a duplicate while making the question.