# Tried previous Swift 3 Recommendation but NotificationCenter Swift 3 Unrecognized Selector for method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Tried this solution: [No Method declared with Objective-C Selector for Notification UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366116/no-method-declared-with-objective-c-selector-for-notification-uikeyboardwillshow)

but still doesn't work

[image: Tried previous solution and even recommended Swift 3 implementation]

[image]

Note: I added pictures because my code are on the same file/class but theyre in different places and theres a lot of code in between.

Basically I created another Class (Non-UIViewController) that sends a Notification to the ViewController Class and followed suggestions from my Xcode and Stackoverflow.

The methods are just to move to another viewcontroller from current viewcontroller, I used notificationcenter because I was reusing a lot of the same methods and just created a class that had the same functions called loginHandler and this uses notification center to send notifications

Comment: `#selector(redirectToHome)` should suffice, but the long form is `#selector(ViewController.redirectToHome(notification:))` unless you change your func to `func redirectToHome(_ notification: Notification)`.

Comment: You don't need the `@objc` if you are a subclass of something that is descended from `NSObject` like `UIViewController` for instance.

Comment: You're right, works now, thanks